# MySQL Service is not starting on linux

Tags: mysql, linux

I am having a problem with my database it does not want to start :(

the server is running on linux centos 6.2

it was working until I emptied the logs I don't know if this have anything to do with my problem !

the log says the following :

```
131212 15:52:05 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
131212 15:52:06  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
131212 15:52:06  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
131212 15:52:06  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
131212 15:52:06  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 2 2565027428
131212 15:52:06 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find     file: 'db' (errno: 2)
131212 15:52:06 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

**Edit**

here is my "my.cnf" :

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

user=mysql
max_connections=1500
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

also this is the output of `ls -l /var/lib/mysql/` :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql 1512046592 Dec 12 17:02 ibdata1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql    5242880 Dec 12 17:19 ib_logfile0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql    5242880 Dec 11 09:54 ib_logfile1
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql       4096 Dec 12 09:02 mysql
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql      12288 Dec 12 17:15 nagios
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql      20480 Dec  9 09:05 nagiosql
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql       4096 Oct 27 10:45 test
```

any suggestions?

Comment: The ur-problem seems to be that: "Can't find file: 'db'". It seems your InnoDB is damaged. You need recovery.

Comment: ok thanks but how can I do this recovery?

Comment: What is your `datadir` ? Goto that folder in Linux, and run `ls -l` and post that output. Also, please post your `/etc/my.cnf` in the question as well.

Comment: You mentioned you emptied the logs. What exactly did you empty? Did you delete the `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` files?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I put them in the question :)

Comment: no @RolandoMySQLDBA I emptied the `/var/log/mysqld.log` using `truncate` command

Comment: I X-Ware, just a question, does the /etc/mysql directory exists?

Comment: @mfouilleul I am afraid not !

Comment: Ok, no it's good, sometimes a "default mysql installation" is present and "mysqld" take /etc/mysql/my.cnf instead of /etc/my.cnf

Comment: Remove your innodb log files (ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1) and restart your instance, MySQL will recreate it.

Comment: @mfouilleul I removed them and tried to start the service but no way .. it failed but it created new copies of them

Comment: Ok, my last advice will to recreate a dir named db (mkdir /var/lib/mysql/db, don't forget to chown the dir "chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/db"), MySQL will think that is a MyISAM db and maybe it'll want to start... then make a clean drop with DROP DATABASE db;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by doing the following :

1. Move all the contents of my data directory (in my case `/var/lib/mysql/` ) to a safe place.
2. Execute the command `service mysqld start`, this will:

   - recreate two DBs:

     - `mysql`
     - `test`
   - recreate `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile0`, and `ib_logfile0`
3. Copy the contents that you backed up (in step 1) from the safe place to the data directory again, of course, except both `mysql` and `test` directories.
4. Using the following command `mysqladmin -u root -p'' password yournewpass` reset the password of your root user.

**An Advice:**

**Always make sure you make a backup of your databases structure and data to avoid looping in such loops, just delete every thing, re-install your engine, and restore your data :)**

Comment: Your luck was your tables are MyISAM :)